# check radio button on click input text (form)

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to change a radio button to checked when a input text is clicked in one FORM.
Here is my form:

```
<input type="radio" name="sel_limit" id="sel_limit_1" value="1" <?php if($limit_days) echo 'checked'?>> <?php echo MOD_CO_DAYS; ?> <input type="text" class="inputbox" name="limit_1" id="limit_1" value="<?php echo $limit_days; ?>" size="5"/>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="sel_limit" id="sel_limit_2" value="2" <?php if($limit_weeks) echo 'checked'?>> <?php echo MOD_CO_WEEKS; ?> <input type="text" class="inputbox" name="limit_2" id="limit_2" value="<?php echo $limit_weeks; ?>" size="5"/>
```

Here js code:

```
$('#limit_1').click(function(){
    $('#limit_2').val('0');
    $('#sel_limit_1').attr('checked', true);
});

$('#limit_2').click(function(){
    $('#limit_1').val('0');
    $('#sel_limit_2').attr('checked', true);
});
```

I tried to use `attr` and `prop` with and without true, nothing happens.
This is not working because is one form?
I'm using jquery 1.8.3

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/6gRkD/

Comment: You might want to try `.prop` again, because it definitely works: http://jsfiddle.net/b38Vr/

Comment: I think OP is not writing his code in DOM ready Try  `$(document).ready(function(){$('#limit_1').click(function(){..... }); });`

Comment: I tried all of this answers, nothing. document.ready is already inside

Comment: @Riturajratan no still the same, maybe because is a FORM??

Comment: can you give me all html here is the question about attr and prop so i have mention the demo thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the new .prop() function:

```
  $('#sel_limit_2').prop('checked', true);
```

jQuery 1.5 and below

The .prop() function is not available, so you need to use .attr().

```
  $('.myCheckbox').attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score -1):

by [attr](https://api.jquery.com/ATTR/) use checked

ALL the DOWNVOTER SEE THIS DEMO AND SEE ITS WORKS **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S6YXw/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#limit_1').click(function(){
     $("input[type='text'").val('');
     $("input[type='radio'").removeAttr("checked"); 
    $('#limit_2').val('0');
    $('#sel_limit_1').attr('checked', 'checked');
});

$('#limit_2').click(function(){
   $("input[type='text'").val('');
   $("input[type='radio'").removeAttr("checked");      
   $('#limit_1').val('0');
    $('#sel_limit_2').attr('checked', 'checked');
 });
});
```

by [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) use true

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#limit_1').click(function(){
      $("input[type='text'").val('');
      $("input[type='radio'").prop("checked",false);     
      $('#limit_2').val('0');
      $('#sel_limit_1').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#limit_2').click(function(){
      $("input[type='text'").val('');
      $("input[type='radio'").prop("checked",false);        
      $('#limit_1').val('0');
      $('#sel_limit_2').prop('checked', true);
});
});
```

Comment: Because `attr` should not be used to set the checked *property*

Comment: true and checked is do the same in jquery

Comment: @RGraham's fiddle solution works fine for me on chrome 34.0.1847.116; nb: using attr fails.

Comment: Hi all see my demo please i don't know why you are saying it not workes i always try above code so i am not agreed with you guys thanks for any suggestions

Comment: if someone you are trying to help tells you, your solution doesn't work, he probably has no malignant intent but simply cannot get your solution to work. therefore you might wish to explore the reason for it instead of just pointing at a demo in another environment. btw, your code is syntactically incorrect (attribute selectors without closing `]`), thus it depends on tolerant parsers.